# how to get html element by the value given to an attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, dom

to a div element inside forloop ,i have given an attribute called 'prod_id',and i have set the value of that attribute to current product id

**html**

```
    {% for product in products %}
    <div prod_id={{product.id}}>
    .....
    </div>
    <button prod={{product.id}}>
    {% endfor %}
```

***jquery***

```
    let product = $(button).attr('prod')
    let fade_prod = $('div[prod_id = product]')
    fade_prod.fadeOut('slow')
```

in second line of jQuery i want to equate prod_id to the value of product. and i've tried equate but the logic isn't working as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that applying your own non-standard attributes in HTML can lead to rendering and styling issues. Thankfully you can use `data` attributes instead to attach your own custom metadata to an element.

From there you can simply use the `prev()` method of jQuery to target the `div` related to the clicked button:

```js
$('button').on('click', e => {
  let $button = $(e.target);
  $button.prev('div').fadeOut('slow');

  console.log($button.data('prod-id'));      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-prod-id="123">123</div>
<button data-prod-id="123">Click me</button>

<div data-prod-id="456">456</div>
<button data-prod-id="456">Click me</button>

<div data-prod-id="789">789</div>
<button data-prod-id="789">Click me</button>
```

If you did still want to target the element by its data attribute, you can use an attribute selector. You simply need to concatenate the value in to the selector:

```js
$('button').on('click', e => {
  let prodId = $(e.target).data('prod-id');
  $(`div[data-prod-id="${prodId}"]`).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-prod-id="123">123</div>
<button data-prod-id="123">Click me</button>

<div data-prod-id="456">456</div>
<button data-prod-id="456">Click me</button>

<div data-prod-id="789">789</div>
<button data-prod-id="789">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks alot , since i'm still a noob to jquery i got to learn alot from your answer